# Detours 3.0 hook GetProcAddresss()

Tags: c++, hook, detours

I'm using:

**MS VS 10**

**Detours v3.0 Express**

The complete source code **DLL**:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
ofstream prclist ;
#pragma comment(lib,"detours.lib")
FARPROC (WINAPI * pGetProcAddress)(HMODULE hModule,LPCSTR lpProcName) = GetProcAddress;
FARPROC WINAPI  myGetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule,LPCSTR lpProcName);
FARPROC WINAPI  myGetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule,LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    prclist << lpProcName << endl; // <- ACCESS_VIOLATION READ
    return pGetProcAddress( hModule, lpProcName);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hDLL, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{

switch(reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            prclist.open("proclst.log",ios::out | ios::app );
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hDLL);
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pGetProcAddress, myGetProcAddress);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            prclist.close();
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)pGetProcAddress, myGetProcAddress);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
            break;
        }
   }
        return TRUE;
}
```

I try to view the list of functions received by GetProcAddress. But after start, the program is closed with an error: "**ACCESS_VIOLATION**, **UNABLE_TO_READ**"

Somebody can prompt how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you trap the AV in a debugger and examine the call stack, etc?

Comment: Excuse, this code doesn't cause an error, I forgot to add:

**prclist << lpProcName << endl; **  - It causes an error

Comment: I updated the source code.

Comment: Result: proclst.log 
<br/> 

...
DecodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
EncodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
EncodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
DecodePointer<br/> 
IsDebuggerPresent<br/> <br/> 
and 

This application has encountered a critical error:



Program: 
Exception: 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION) at 001B:604DD950

The instruction at '0x604DD950' referenced memory at '0x00000068'.
The memory could not be 'read'.

Press OK to terminate the application.
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------

Comment: This helps a lot.  The code is dereferencing an object pointer to read a member.  The pointer is null and the member is 104 bytes offset, resulting in the failure to read at 0x00000068.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference page, for `lpProcName`:

> The function or variable name, or the **function's ordinal value.** If this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word; the high-order word must be zero.

This means it *might* not be a pointer to string but the replacement function always treats it at such. This is a possible cause of the access violation as it will be using an integer value (`182` for example) as the starting memory address of a null terminated string.

Use [`HIWORD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to correct:

```
if (HIWORD(lpProcName))
{
    prclist << "name: " << lpProcName << std::endl;
}
else
{
    prclist << "ordinal: " << reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(lpProcName) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @DOLBOEB: [Don't use `IsBadReadPtr`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx). Check the high order word explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment.  Looks like the stream just needs to be tested for being open before insertion operators (<<) are used on it.